# Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column **PART_TRAN_TYPE** whose unique values are Credit and Debit.

Now I want to create a new column `money` and append -Debit and +Credit to it. but I get the above error which I don't get when I try to check if dataframe is greater than a certain value like `df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"][i] > 100`

I also tried using `if (df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"] == 'D').all()` buy the loop runs for ever

```
def money(df):
    '''
    Creates a column for depicting the Credit and Debit numerically
    '''
    money = []
    for i in df.index:
        
        if df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"][i] == 'Debit':
            money.append(-df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"][i])
        else:
            money.append(df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"][i])

    return (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(money, columns=["flow"])], axis=1))
```

Traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b7c676b1323b> in <module>
----> 1 money = money(clean_data)

<ipython-input-10-28fb0733adb8> in money(df)
      6     for i in df.index:
      7 
----> 8         if df["PART_TRAN_TYPE"][i] == 'Debit':
     10             money.append(-df["Debit"][i])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler to do a vectorised solution

```
import numpy as np
s = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"PART_TRAN_TYPE":np.random.choice(["Debit","Credit"],s),
             "VALUE":np.random.randint(1,100,s)})


df.assign(money=df["VALUE"]*np.where(df.PART_TRAN_TYPE.eq("Credit"), 1,-1))
```

|  | PART_TRAN_TYPE | VALUE | money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Debit | 65 | -65 |
| 1 | Debit | 51 | -51 |
| 2 | Debit | 61 | -61 |
| 3 | Credit | 36 | 36 |
| 4 | Credit | 21 | 21 |
| 5 | Debit | 51 | -51 |
| 6 | Debit | 69 | -69 |
| 7 | Debit | 9 | -9 |
| 8 | Debit | 89 | -89 |
| 9 | Debit | 60 | -60 |

Comment: Thanks  @Rob Raymond This was a exactly what I needed. I discovered that as the size of `s` grows large, it take lot's of time perform the computation. e.g `s=500000` is there a way increase the speed?

Also I wasn't thinking of this solution at all. can you recommend a link that can help me improve my pandas and numpy skills

Comment: you won't get much faster than this for large data frames.  It's already a fully vectorised solution.  I don't have any specific recommended reading.  just a simple rule of thumb,  never use loops with data :-)